# Converting a integer into a 8 bit binary with a for

Tags: javascript, binary, numbers, bit

Hello i've seen this question asked many times, but im still quite confused.
I would like to convert a integer number into 8bit binary version.
im writing something like this.

```
function dec2bin(dec){
  let b=[]
  b=(dec.toString(2))

  return c
}
//ill get dec2bin(10)
1010
//desired
00001010
```

If is possible i would like to use the "for" making it adding 0 until its 8 bit.
something like->

```
for(i=0; i<8 ;i++)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `<binary string>.padStart(8).replaceAll(' ', "0")`? Example: `"1010".padStart(8).replaceAll(' ', "0")` returns `"00001010"`

Comment: Also, why are you declaring `b` as an array, setting `b` to a string, and then returning the non-existent `c` variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `padStart(8, "0")` in order to add extra 0s to the start of it, bringing it to the desired length.

```js
function dec2bin(dec) {
    return dec.toString(2).padStart(8, "0");
}
console.log(dec2bin(10))
```

```html
Number: <input type="number" id="input"></input><br />
<button onclick="console.log(dec2bin(Number(document.getElementById('input').value)))">Convert</button>
```

Comment: Oh awesome thanks, and how would i the two's complement of the initial number before adding the 0s to fill the number up?

Comment: If you're trying to get the number unpadded, you can just omit the `padStart(8, "0")` in the function (`return dec.toString(2);`)

Comment: mh no i mean doing the 2's complement such as (~n + 1 >>> 0).toString(2) can i do something like this return (~dec+1>>>0).toString(2).padStart(8,"0");     ahahah?